# how to write output of the monitor to a file

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have a testbench and a verilog modules. I want to write ouput of the testbench to a file anmed as output.txt. While doing this job, I want to use $monitor.

Is it possible ? If yes, can you give me pseudo code of that segment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have wrote Makefile to meet that desire ;

```
default :
iverilog -o verilog_testbench lab_work.v test_bench.v 
odt  :
./verilog_testbench > simulation.odt
txt  :
./verilog_testbench > simulation.txt
```

I have tried  Taniwha 's answer before, but It did not work. So, I have wrote Makefile.

Answer (score 6):

use $fmonitor:

```
integer f;
initial begin
  f = $fopen("output.txt");
  $fmonitor(f, "time=%5d, v=%h\n", $time, vv);
  #1000 
  $fclose(f);
  $finish;
end
```